# Warn about calling copy ctor when std::move'ing

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Given a program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Vec {
    Vec() = default;

    Vec(const Vec& vec) 
        : v_(vec.v_)
    {
        cout << "copy Vec" << endl;
    }

    Vec(Vec&& vec)
        : v_(std::move(vec.v_))
    {
        cout << "move Vec" << endl;
    }

    vector<double> v_{};
};

struct T1 {
    Vec Value;
};

struct T2 {
    T2(const T1& t1) 
        : Value(std::move(t1.Value))
    {

    }

    Vec Value;
};

struct T3 {
    T3(T1&& t1)
        : Value(std::move(t1.Value))
    {

    }

    Vec Value;
};

int main() {
    T1 t1;

    T2 t2{ t1 };

    T3 t3{ std::move(t1) };

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
copy Vec
move Vec
```

In both cases I `std::move`'ing `t1.Value` to `Vec` ctor.

Is there any possibility to enable some warning in Clang (or another compiler) so it warns me that moving actually calls copy constructor?

(Clang already can warn about performance issues when, for example, I return a `std::unique_ptr` by `std::move(result)` from function.)

Comment: Do note the `std::move` doesn't actually move anything.  It just performs a cast.

Comment: Performance issues when you std::move a `unique_ptr` to return it from a function? What're you talking about? That literally resolves to one or two pointer assignments.

Comment: @David: Yes, but with named return value elision, the compiler could have turned it into *nothing*. That is, if he didn't needlessly use `std::move`. It's a perfectly valid warning.

Comment: @NicolBolas if it was a local to that function, true

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any possibility to enable some warning in Clang (or another compiler) so it warns me that moving actually calls copy constructor?

The process of moving doesn't have to do with calling `std::move` specifically. That just performs a cast. A move happens when you call a move constructor/assignment operator. Moves can happen without calling `std::move` (the case your compiler warned you about, for example), and as you saw moves may not happen even if you use `std::move`.

You cannot move from a `const` reference because... it's *`const`*. Movement is destructive and therefore requires the ability to modify the object. Which `const` doesn't allow.

Movement is ultimately an optimized copy operation. So performing a copy instead of a move is generally OK, particularly if the type doesn't have a move constructor.

If you want, you could write your own version of `std::move` that `static_assert`s that the `T` is not `const`:

```
template< class T >
constexpr typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& my_move( T&& t )
{
    static_assert(!std::is_const<T>::value, "Cannot move from a const reference");
    return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t);
}
```

Comment: `!std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value`: `int const&` is not `const`.

Comment: @Yakk: Um... why isn't `const int &` considered `const`? The standard just says "T is `const` qualified".

Comment: References cannot be const qualified.  They can refer to a const-qualified type, but they themselves are not const qualified.  This is one of many reasons why `const int&` is a misleading way to write `int const&`.  `const` applies to `int` here.

Comment: Hello Nicol. I _know_ that std::move is simply a cast to rvalue. Question is not about this. Clang can statically at the time of compilation detect that there is a cast and there is a copy-ctor called, not move-ctor. Because we are casting to `T&&` and calling ctor with `const T&` while there DO exists ctor with `T&&`. That is the question.

Comment: @vladon: You aren't casting to a `T&&`; that's my point. You are casting to a **`const`** `T&&`. A `const T&&` will not bind to a parameter of type ` T&&`, so it instead calls the overload that takes the next nearest thing: `const T&`.